# Clojure: How to iterate over a list of objects to create a (reporting) object? Convert list of objects to key/val hash

Tags: clojure

I am trying to iterate over a list in order to create a report upon its contents. How do you convert something that looks like this:

```
(
    {
        :_id  "123"
        :keya "aaa"
        :keyb "bbb"
    }
    {
        :_id  "456"
        :keya "ccc"
        :keyb "ddd"
    }
    {
        :_id  "789"
        :keya "eee"
        :keyb "fff"
    }
)
```

into something that looks like this?:

```
{
    :123 {
        :_id  "123"
        :keya "aaa"
        :keyb "bbb"
    }
    :456 {
        :_id  "456"
        :keya "ccc"
        :keyb "ddd"
    }

    :789 {
        :_id  "789"
        :keya "eee"
        :keyb "fff"
    }
}
```

I am very grateful for help you could offer.

EDIT: WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR

```
(defn fetchAndReport [idarray]

    (let [fetched_objs       (mc/find-maps mongoconnection ncoll {:_id { "$in" idarray }})
          bad_report         (zipmap idarray fetched_objs) ;; mismatched keys with wrong objs - can't count on payload order
          post_fetched_ids   (map (fn [element] (get-in element [:_id])) fetched_objs)
          long_way_report    (zipmap post_fetched_ids fetched_objs)]

          long_way_report
    )
)
```

Comment: Benjamin, please let us know what you already tried out and what your problems were with that.

Comment: @StefanKamphausen thanks for your note. I added what I tried so far. I'm curious how I might accomplish this with a "reduce" type approach?

Comment: "reduce" meaning that I am building-up (adding key/vals to) the {} as I iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it but I'm not sure this is the cleanest syntax:

```
(defn createReportFromObjArray [inputarray]

    (reduce (fn [returnobj elementobj]

                (let [_id (get-in elementobj [:_id])
                      keyword (keyword _id)]

                    (assoc returnobj keyword elementobj)
                )
            )
            {}
            inputarray)
)
```

Comment: Benjamin, a comment on your code, only to be helpful since you are new to clojure -- the naming and spacing resembles something like Java.  In clojure, camelCase is not used, but rather kebab-case.  The length of var names are often much shorter than what you've used, and while this may seem contrary to what you are used to, there is a good reason for it, though at times longer names are more desirable. Likewise, too much spacing makes for more difficult readability. Last, spacing is pretty well agreed upon and can be found here,first 2 sections:  https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide

Comment: Benjamin, the solution you ended with is correct but may be tightened. `(reduce (fn [acc x] .... (assoc acc k v)) {} coll)` is a common pattern and rewrites to `(into {} (map (fn [x] ... [k v]) coll))` (using seqs – also expressible as `(into {} (for [x coll] (... [k v])))`) or `(into {} (map (fn [x] ... [k v])) coll)` (using transducers). The transducer version is equivalent to yours except it allocates an extra pair for each item.If it bothers you, you can use my xforms lib: `(x/into {} (x/by-key (comp keyword :_id) identity) coll)` or `(x/into {} (x/for [x %] [(keyword (:_id x)) x]) coll)`

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn report [items]
  (into {} (map (fn [{id :_id :as m}] [(keyword id) m]) items)))
```

Comment: Simpler still, `(defn report [items] (group-by (comp keyword :_id) items))`

Comment: as in the other answer with group-by, the value for each key in your solution is an array with one element. Is there an easy way for the value of each key to just be the object itself?

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren just posted an answer that matches your requirement

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren - The values in the map returned by this function are the maps themselves.

Comment: `(into {} (map (juxt (comp keyword :_id) identity) items))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Clojure built-in `group-by` function:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def x
  [
    {
        :_id  "123"
        :keya "aaa"
        :keyb "bbb"
    }
    {
        :_id  "456"
        :keya "ccc"
        :keyb "ddd"
    }
    {
        :_id  "789"
        :keya "eee"
        :keyb "fff"
    }
  ] )

(def y (group-by #(:_id %) x))
(pprint y)


> lein run
{"123" [{:_id "123", :keya "aaa", :keyb "bbb"}],
 "456" [{:_id "456", :keya "ccc", :keyb "ddd"}],
 "789" [{:_id "789", :keya "eee", :keyb "fff"}]}
```

Comment: the value for each key in your solution is an array with one element. Is there an easy way for the value of each key to just be the object itself?

Comment: Since there might be more than one item corresponding to "123"m for example, `group-by` returns a list of all the matching items in a vector. If you know there is just one item, you can say `(first (y "123))` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just to slightly improve upon an already good answer:

```
(into {} (map (juxt (comp keyword :_id) identity) input))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward, creates a map with the key, then merges them together:

```
(defn rpt [o]
  (apply merge 
    (map #(array-map (keyword (:_id %)) %) o)))
```

Comment: this passes over the original array 3 times? how many times does the answer I posted below pass? I think mine is 1 time?

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren in higher level declarative programming, we are not concerned with "passing over" or iterations, in general.  We do want to give attention to performance, but it's higher level than an iterative approach.  As a functional programmer, the concern is not how to do something, but what the result should be -- the language runtime will handle all of those details, and can optimize more easily (in theory), because the programmer has not specified how to do the work, but what the result should be.

Comment: if that's the case, then how is your solution better (faster?) than the one I listed in the original question as "WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR"

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren Your solution is just fine (your solution, not the code in your original question) -- if so, not sure why you're still working on it.  Your original questions says nothing about producing the absolute fastest code, and faster is not always better anyway...  You have taken a `reduce` approach, which is a good one.  It is the main way your brain will approach problems now (a more iterative style), because you have not programmed in a functional language before.  Many approaches work, and only you can prioritize what's most important-readability, speed, easier to parallelize etc

Comment: thanks for your help and your critic on my conventions. Always am looking for the log(n) approach if possible

Comment: _As a functional programmer, the concern is not how to do something, but what the result should be -- the language runtime will handle all of those details._  I disagree. The sufficiently smart compiler|runtime doesn't exist. I believe it's better to have some sympathy for the underlying system: it informs our tradeoffs. For example here I believe `reduce` is superior to `apply` because it's more specific (it conveys more information both to the reader and the not-smart-enough runtime). (1/2)

Comment: Consider: `(into {} (map (fn [x] [(keyword (:_id x)) x])) o)`. By using `into` it taps in the reduce infrastructure and its optimizations and using transducers allows to cut on allocations. (2/2)

Comment: @cgrand To clarify, I don't mean to throw caution to the wind and enter the purely theoretical world of functional programming--certainly, practical considerations must be taken into account.  In this context though, the poster has not written any clojure code before, and is approaching the problem from the other paradigm.  A middle-ground must be found, and he's very far to one side (and perhaps I'm too far to the other side! :-).  I like your solution and it's the most readable and fastest.  Thanks for showing a good use of the transducer.  Have a good day!